# Sorting a report by Date using Microsoft SQL Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am using Microsoft SQL Report Builder and like to sort a report by [FromDate] which is formatted as such 21/02/2019 10:05 am as following:

```
=FORMAT(Fields!FromDate.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt")
```

I think I got an idea how to sort the report by date by going to Tablix Properties > Sorting > Add > Sort by [FromDate] Order: A to Z but it does not sort them ...

I have also set the FromDate column to category: Date

Furthermore, I thought I would also need to change the expression within the Sorting section and tried as such:

```
=FORMAT(Fields!FromDate.Value,"yyyy.MM.dd")
```

Still, the report shows 18/02/2019 10:15 AM before 01/02/2019 06:30 AM

Any suggestions?

Thanks

---

UPDATE

Because I was using group by within the report and I did not use the Sorting within the right section < this was the reason why the sorting of the date did not show in correct order.

Well, sorting of the dates were in order within each group but then the group order was not in tact. So, all I needed to do was to select the 1st column where the group by is set and then set the sorting in there.

In other words the report shows something like this

Group By: Title

Title 1 (contains few entries with the dates)
01/02/2019 
05/02/2019
22/02/2019

Title 2 (contains few entries with the dates)
02/02/2019
09/02/2019
01/03/2019

Title 3 (contains few entries with the dates)
25/02/2019
04/04/2019

Booooooom, issue solved :)

Comment: FromDate type is date or string?

Comment: @niktrs the date cell is set to Date (I have also set the FromDate column to category: Date)

Comment: By the way, does grouping have an effect on the sorting by date?

Comment: What matters is the database field to be datetime not string. Setting the column to date inside reporting services defines the format not the data type

Comment: Yes the group expression should also be set to be the unformatted date. Group on date, sort on date. Use formatting only for display reasons on the textbox expression

Comment: Yes, the DataSet pulls the info from SharePoint and in SP the FromDate and UntilDate are set to Date & Time. So yes it is date format ... but I guess the Grouping is now the factor because ... I noticed that a few items are grouped together and within the group the dates are in order :)

Comment: Question is ... how do I get a group that starts with e.g. 01/02/2019 to be on top of the queue and then the next group to be according to the dates. ... difficult to explain in words

Comment: Huuuuurrreeeeeyy :) haah, such a silly mistake I made, wow .... thanks Niktrs for pointing me at the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Because I was using group by within the report and I did not use the Sorting within the right section < this was the reason why the sorting of the date did not show in correct order.

Well, sorting of the dates were in order within each group but then the group order was not in tact. So, all I needed to do was to select the 1st column where the group by is set and then set the sorting in there.

In other words the report shows something like this

Group By: Title

Title 1 (contains few entries with the dates) 01/02/2019 05/02/2019 22/02/2019

Title 2 (contains few entries with the dates) 02/02/2019 09/02/2019 01/03/2019

Title 3 (contains few entries with the dates) 25/02/2019 04/04/2019

Booooooom, issue solved :)